# disable UIKIT 3 file upload ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, uikit

in UIKIT3, when use file upload component, after file select and load, an ajax take place and file uploaded without any form submit. how to prevent it? i use jquery form plugin.
this is my code:

```
UIkit.upload('.js-upload', {
    url:$('#new_certificate_form').attr('action'),
    name: 'new_cert_img',
    loadEnd:function () {
        alert('ok');
    },
    completeAll:function () {
        $('#new_cert_file_name').html($(this).val().replace(/C:\\fakepath\\/i, ''));
    }
});

$('#new_certificate_form').submit(function () {
    $(this).ajaxSubmit({
        success: function () {
            UIkit.modal('#new_certificate').hide();
            $('#new_certificate_form').resetForm();
            UIkit.notification('تغییرات با موفقیت انجام شد.', {
                status: 'primary',
                pos: 'bottom-right',
                timeout: 3000
            });
        },
        fail: function () {
            UIkit.notification('خطایی رخ داده! لطفا صفحه را مجددا بارگذاری نموده و دوباره تلاش کنید.', {
                status: 'primary',
                pos: 'bottom-right',
                timeout: 3000
            });
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the 'method' property to a function that returns false.  This stops the ajax request taking place.

You can then grab the files from the beforeAll event.

```js
    UIkit.upload('.js-upload', {
      multiple: false,
      method: () => {return false;},
      beforeAll: function (el, files) {
        console.log('beforeAll', arguments);
        console.log('el', el);
        console.log('files', files);
      }
    });
```